# ESP8266 + NodeMCU Custom Build + WS2812 Not Working

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, esplorer

I got this build on my ESP8266-12E using

```
Vins-MacBook-Pro:esptool-master vin$ sudo ./esptool.py --port /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash -fm qio 0x00000 nodemcu-dev-8-modules-2017-02-23-16-42-03-integer.bin 

NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
branch: dev
commit: b382a42057a264eba55e3781e18143f52e0b426e
SSL: false
modules: file,gpio,net,node,tmr,uart,wifi,ws2812
build   built on: 2017-02-23 16:41
powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.0.0(656edbf)
```

1)When I execute following in ESPlorer

```
ws2812.init()
ws2812.write(string.char(255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0))
```

console shows following & no ws2812b pixel lights up.

```
ws2812.init()ws2812.write(string.char(255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0))
```

2)When I execute following in ESPlorer

```
ws2812.init()
ws2812.write(1,string.char(255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0))
```

console shows following & no ws2812b pixel lights up.

```
ws2812.init()ws2812.write(1,string.char(255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0))
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to writ
```

Please guide, Thank You!

Comment: Update : With nodemcu_integer_0.9.6-dev_20150704.bin output was on GPIO5 but now with custom build nodemcu-dev-8-modules-2017-02-23-16-42-03-integer.bin output is on GPIO2. Now //ws2812.init()
ws2812.write(string.char(128, 0, 128):rep(10)) // lights up all 10  ws2812b pixels

Comment: Update : buffer doesn't work `ws2812.init()
buffer = ws2812.newBuffer(10, 3)
buffer:set(5, string.char(0, 255, 0))` has no output/led doesn't change

Comment: Update : buffer worked ... following was missing 'ws2812.write(buffer)' :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comments to the question.
It will help someone else having same issues.

Comment: You can answer your own question. If you think you've solved the problem. Just answer your question and accept the answer. Thus you can help others.